# How to access ng-model name dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

How do I access ng-model name assigned to each div dynamically in for loop in function which I'm calling on ng-click?

I've four divs in my page and at a time i want to display only one and hide others.
I'm trying to do this using ng-show.

```
<div ng-show="content0">content0 details here...</div>
<div ng-show="content1">content1 details here... </div>
<div ng-show="content2">content2 details here...</div>
<div ng-show="content3">content3 details here... </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
<div ng-show="current == 0">content0 details here...</div>
<div ng-show="current == 1">content1 details here... </div>
<div ng-show="current == 2">content2 details here...</div>
<div ng-show="current == 3">content3 details here... </div>
```

and in ng-click set $scope.current to the one you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Off of the model you would have a Boolean property to say if it was hidden or not.  You would modify this in your loop when calling ngClick.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/roadprophet/ffKTy/

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <div ng-repeat="thing in things">
            <div ng-show="thing.shown">
                <h3>{{thing.id}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button ng-click="flipMode()">FLIP!</button>
    </div>
</div>

angular.module('app', []).
controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.things = [{
        id: 1,
        shown: true
    }, {
        id: 2,
        shown: false
    }, {
        id: 3,
        shown: true
    }, {
        id: 4,
        shown: false
    }, {
        id: 5,
        shown: true
    }, ];
    $scope.flipMode = function () {
        $scope.things.forEach(function (thing) {
            thing.shown = !thing.shown
        })
    };
}]);
```